# Maximum Likelihood estimate of Covariance Matrix of the Multivariate Gaussian Linear Model

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, covariance-matrix

Consider the following linear model

\begin{align}
    \mathbf{y}_l = \mathbf{H}\mathbf{x}_l + \mathbf{v}_l, \quad l = 1, 2, \cdots, L
\end{align}

where $\mathbf{y}_l$ is $N \times 1$ measurement vector, $\mathbf{H}$ is a known $N \times M$ measurement matrix, $\mathbf{x}_l$ is a $M \times 1$ deterministic unknown parameters needs to be estimated and  $\mathbf{v}_l$ is a $N \times 1$  zero-mean Gaussian noise vector $\mathbf{v}_l \sim \mathcal{N} \left( \mathbf{0}, \mathbf{\Sigma} \right)$ where $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is the $N \times N$ covariance matrix.

In this model, I am interested in first estimating the unknown parameters $\left( \mathbf{\Sigma}, \mathbf{x}_l \right)$ by maximum likelihood method, and then compute the likelihood function $\log \left( p\left( \mathbf{Y}; \mathbf{\Sigma}, \mathbf{x}_l \right)  \right)$ where where $\mathbf{Y} = \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{y}_1& \mathbf{y}_2 & \cdots & \mathbf{y}_L
\end{bmatrix}$ represents the data samples stacked into $N \times L$ matrix.

The probability density function of $\mathbf{Y}$ is
\begin{align}
    p\left( \mathbf{Y}; \mathbf{\Sigma}, \mathbf{x}_l \right) &= \dfrac{1}{\left( 2\pi \right)^ {LN/2}\det( \mathbf{\Sigma})^{L/2}}\exp \left (-\dfrac{1}{2} \left( \sum_{l=1}^L \mathrm{tr} \left( \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} \left(\mathbf{y}_l - \mathbf{H} \mathbf{x}_l \right) \left(\mathbf{y}_l - \mathbf{H} \mathbf{x}_l \right) ^T \right) \right)    \right)
\end{align}
Continuing in the standard way, i.e, maximizing the logarithm of the pdf with respect to the unknowns and finding their maximum likelihood estimates, the following estimates are found (I include the derivations as well)

\begin{equation}
 \log \left( p\left( \mathbf{Y}|H_0; \mathbf{\Sigma}, \mathbf{x}_l \right)  \right) = -\dfrac{LN}{2}\log 2\pi - \dfrac{L}{2}\log \det(\mathbf{\Sigma}) - \dfrac{1}{2} \mathrm{tr} \left( \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}   \sum_{l=1}^L  \left(\mathbf{y}_l - \mathbf{H} \mathbf{x}_l \right) \left(\mathbf{y}_l - \mathbf{H} \mathbf{x}_l \right) ^T  \right).    
 \end{equation}

Taking the differential of the above expression,

\begin{align}
     \mathbf{dd} \left(  p\left( \mathbf{Y}; \mathbf{\Sigma}, \mathbf{x}_l \right) \right) &= -\dfrac{L}{2}\mathrm{tr} \left( \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} \mathbf{dd}{\mathbf{\Sigma}} \right) - \dfrac{1}{2} \mathrm{tr} \left( - \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} \mathbf{dd}{\mathbf{\Sigma}} \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} \sum_{l=1}^L\left(\mathbf{y}_l - \mathbf{H} \mathbf{x}_l \right) \left(\mathbf{y}_l - \mathbf{H} \mathbf{x}_l \right) ^T   \right) \\ 
    & -\dfrac{1}{2}  \mathrm{tr} \left( \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} \left( \sum_{l=1}^L\left(- \mathbf{H} \mathbf{dd}{x}_l \right) \left(\mathbf{y}_l - \mathbf{H} \mathbf{x}_l \right) ^T + \left(\mathbf{y}_l - \mathbf{H} \mathbf{x}_l \right) \left(-\mathbf{H} \mathbf{dd}\mathbf{x}_l \right)^T  \right ) \right),   
\end{align}

and defining the sample covariance matrix as follows:
\begin{equation}
  \mathbf{T}_0 = \dfrac{1}{L}  \sum_{l=1}^L\left(\mathbf{y}_l - \mathbf{H} \mathbf{x}_l \right) \left(\mathbf{y}_l - \mathbf{H} \mathbf{x}_l \right) ^T.   
\end{equation} then the following equation is found
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{dd} \left(  p\left( \mathbf{Y}; \mathbf{\Sigma}, \mathbf{x}_l \right) \right) &=    -\dfrac{L}{2} \mathrm{tr} \left( \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}    \mathbf{dd}{\mathbf{\Sigma}}  \left(\mathbf{I} - \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} \mathbf{T}_0   \right)  \right) -  \mathrm{tr} \left( \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} \left( \sum_{l=1}^L \mathbf{H}^T \left(\mathbf{y}_l - \mathbf{H} \mathbf{x}_l \right) \left(-   \mathbf{dd}{x}_l \right)^T  \right ) \right).
\end{align}

Then, $\mathbf{H}^T \left(\mathbf{y}_l - \mathbf{H} \mathbf{x}_l \right) = \mathbf{0} \Longrightarrow \hat{\mathbf{x}}_{l} = \left( \mathbf{H}^T \mathbf{H} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{H}^T \mathbf{y}_l $. Note that the estimate  $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_l$ as in classical LS solution. Thus, $\mathbf{H}\hat{\mathbf{x}}_l = \mathbf{H}\left( \mathbf{H}^T \mathbf{H} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{H}^T \mathbf{y}_l  = \mathbf{P}_H\mathbf{y}_l$ where $\mathbf{P}_H$ is the projection matrix.
For the covariance matrix,
\begin{align}
  \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1} \mathbf{T} &= \mathbf{0} \\ 
  &\Downarrow \nonumber 
  \\ \hat{\mathbf{\Sigma}} &= \mathbf{T} \\
                        &=   \dfrac{1}{L}  \sum_{l=1}^L\left(\mathbf{y}_l - \mathbf{H} \hat{\mathbf{x}}_l \right) \left(\mathbf{y}_l - \mathbf{H} \hat{\mathbf{x}}_l \right) ^T \\
                        &=  \dfrac{1}{L}  \sum_{l=1}^L\left(\mathbf{y}_l -  \mathbf{P}_H\mathbf{y}_l \right) \left(\mathbf{y}_l - \mathbf{P}_H\mathbf{y}_l \right) ^T \\
                        &=  \dfrac{1}{L}  \sum_{l=1}^L\left(\mathbf{P}_H^\perp \mathbf{y}_l  \mathbf{y}_l^T \mathbf{P}_H^\perp \right) \label{eq:covariance matrix final form} \\
                        &= \mathbf{P}_H^\perp \dfrac{1}{L} \left( \sum_{l=1}^L \mathbf{y}_l  \mathbf{y}_l^T    \right) \mathbf{P}_H^\perp \\ 
\end{align}

where $\mathbf{P}_H^\perp = \mathbf{I} - \mathbf{P}_H$.
As can be seeen, the rank of covariance matrix estimate is $N-M$ and its determinant is zero and cannot be used in the likelihood function. I would like to know whether 1) I am doing something wrong in the derivation, 2) or this model cannot be solved to achieve positive definite covariance matrix and then meaningfull likelihood function, later to be used in the hypothesis function 3) or if I say that across $L$ snapshots $\mathbf{x}_l$ does not change, I think it can be solved in standard way.

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi: For the covariance matrix estimate, what's wrong with leaving out the last two steps of your derivation and just having the estimate as a function of $P_{H}$. That looks like the multivariate analogue of the sample variance ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't see any problem with seperating $\mathbf{P}_H$ from the summation, because $\mathbf{P}_H$ does not depend on the summation index.

Comment: Hi Osman: I see what you're doing and forget my comment. But what I don't understand is that this seems like a standard multivariate linear regression where $x_l$ could be of thought of as $\beta_{l}$, say  and the $H$ matrix could be thought of as $X$. Is that right ? If so, I think the results are pretty standard and should be on the net. What is it in your formulation that is making the rank zero. Is that just because there are more rows than columns ?  I'll goggle on the net to see if I can find anything similar.

Comment: Can you not stack your response columns  next to each other and make a matrix out of the response ? if so, then I think that your setup corresponds to pg 47 of these slides at the link below. Atleast, I hope it does. If it does, then I imagine that the rest of the derivation follows accordingly. So, go to the link below and then click on multivariate linear regression starting at slide 47. I didn't study carefully but it looks similar to your setup except that the response is a matrix.  http://users.stat.umn.edu/~helwig/teaching.html

Comment: Hello mlofton. Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I will go over the link that you provided and study  again. I will write down what I have found here. The problem was that although it seems standard, there are some assumptions on the vector or matrix to be estimated. Usually, what I found, the matrix of parameters, here it is $\mathbf{x}_l$ s, the usual assumption is that  across the columns they are same, meaning  $\mathbf{x}_l =\mathbf{x}$. See next comment.

Comment: Basically, we are estimating only one set of vector according to the statistics book that I have looked at. But the material that you put seems very  close to my problem. I will check it carefully and share my findings here. Thanks again. Best regards.

Comment: Hi Osman: I hope it helps you.  The link wasn't complete as you noticed. In case others, look at this thread, one has to click on the link and then  go to the multivatiate statistics section and then click on multivariate regression. The  explanation for that formulation starts on slide 47.